# php for and foreach loop only storing last value

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping though one initial array, and specifying values i want. Then i am storing the values i need in an array. Then i am combining those values into a new array, with keys and values. The new array is only storing the last entry of all the data that has been passed to it.

```
$exampleArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $exampleArray[] = array(
        $A1 =  $Anotherarray[$i][25],
        $A2 = $Anotherarray[$i][26],
        $A3 = $Anotherarray[$i][24],
        $A4 = $Anotherarray[$i][27],
        $A5 = $Anotherarray[$i][28]
    );

    $secondExample = array();

    foreach( $A1 as $i => $val )
    {
        $secondExample[] = array(
            "Field1" => $val,
            "Field2" => ucfirst($A2[$i]),
            "Field3" => ucfirst($A3[$i]),
            "Field4" => ucfirst($A4[$i]),
            "Field5" => ucfirst($A5[$i])
        );
    }
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting it with an empty array on each iteration.

Comment: You're overwriting the values like that.

Comment: How can i do this without overwriting the values?

Comment: `array($A1 = 'foo')` is the same as `$A1 = 'foo'; array('foo')`. Somehow I doubt that's the intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `$secondExample` as a new array on every iteration. Do it like this:

```
$exampleArray = array();
$secondExample = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $exampleArray[] = array(
        $A1 = $Anotherarray[$i][25],
        $A2 = $Anotherarray[$i][26],
        $A3 = $Anotherarray[$i][24],
        $A4 = $Anotherarray[$i][27],
        $A5 = $Anotherarray[$i][28]
    );

    $secondExample[$i] = array();
    foreach( $A1 as $j => $val) {
        $secondExample[$i][] = array(
        "Field1" => $val,
        "Field2" => ucfirst($A2[$j]),
        "Field3" => ucfirst($A3[$j]),
        "Field4" => ucfirst($A4[$j]),
        "Field5" => ucfirst($A5[$j])
    );
}
```

Comment: Doing this in to loops running at the same time is causing my browser to become very slow and not load. I am looping though a lot of data, is there a way to do this and not impact performance?

Comment: I think there was kind of a mess with the indices. Try now. Even then, I don't really get what you're trying to do so I'm afraid without knowing more I can't help you simplify this... It is O(n^2) so with a lot of data you'll get bad performance.

Comment: Thanks, it loads now, but for some reason i am still only getting the last entry

Answer (score 0):

As because you are overwriting every time the loop goes.Use array_push

```
 $secondExample = array();

foreach( $A1 as $i => $val )
{
    $varArray = array(
        "Field1" => $val,
        "Field2" => ucfirst($A2[$i]),
        "Field3" => ucfirst($A3[$i]),
        "Field4" => ucfirst($A4[$i]),
        "Field5" => ucfirst($A5[$i])
    );
    array_push($secondExample, $varArray);
}
```